# Angular 5 : How to load data from a CSV stored locally

Tags: angular, csv

I am working on Angular 5, NodeJS v6.11.0

I am trying to create a SPA that will work locally ( not hosted ).
I already have my data in a CSV file ( excel exported to CSV )

How can I load a locally stored CSV file with Angular 5 on windows?
Like C:\data\expences.csv

Comment: You are using electron i suppose, you can find the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722450/electron-function-to-read-a-local-file-fs-not-reading

Comment: Hi, Nopes not electron.
I've been searching but I seem to be going towards MEAN ( Express )