# How to play an audio file in JavaScript with just the full path

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, electron

I have a full path of an audio file, for example

`/Volumes/Transcend/Music/Eric Clapton/Journeyman/01 Pretending.m4a`

I want to load the selected file into an audio player and play the song.  But I don't know how to get file data from the full path.  I don't want to use a file input and get the user to select one file, the point of the app is to ask for an overarching music directory, then list the artists/albums and songs etc.  So I know the path but can't figure out what I need to play the song.

I have a `new Audio()` object, and obviously loading in the full path doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is an electron app I'm writing for Mac desktop.  the files will be stored locally on the user's machine.

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Comment: @duxfox-- I think the fact that this is [tag:electron] might be important.

Comment: but.... audio from server or user's PC/phone?

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález — It's an electron app

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272451/electron-js-images-from-local-file-system

Comment: @Quentin, ok, but you're not answering and it's very important: Files are uploaded before playing?

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález — Why are you asking about files being "uploaded"? Do you know what electron is? (If not, then follow the link on the tag to the tag wiki)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722450/electron-function-to-read-a-local-file-fs-not-reading

Comment: @Quentin. Ok, sorry, I didn't know what Electron is. Now, do you get any error when you try to assign the file? What exactly do the error say? Did you try preppending the `file://` protocol? Did you try replacing `/` bars with `\ `?

Comment: Another one: Did you try replacing spaces with `%20`? I mean, using encodeURI(url) function.