# Electron open file/directory in specific application

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm building a sort of File explorer / Finder using Electron. 
I want to open some file types with a specific application.

I've tried the approach from this answer: 
[Open external file with Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381450/open-external-file-with-electron)

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'
spawn('/path/to/app/superApp.app', ['/path/to/file'])
```

But when I do that, I get a `EACCES` error as follows.

**Is this the right approach? If yes, how can I fix the issue? If not, what is the right approach?**

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can open a file or folder through shell commands from the electron module. The commands work on both main and renderer process.

```
const {shell} = require('electron') // deconstructing assignment

shell.showItemInFolder('filepath') // Show the given file in a file manager. If possible, select the file.
shell.openPath('folderpath') // Open the given file in the desktop's default manner.
```

More info on https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/shell.md

Comment: And you can also try `shell.showItemInFolder('filepath')` to open the folder and select the file

Comment: I think the original question was how to open a file in a specific application. For example: open a .css file in “Visual Studio Code” and not the default application which might be “Text Edit”.

Comment: I believe you are correct @FlorianSchulz. I updated the accepted answer with what I found at the link originally provided (and accepted by the original question asker). That said, I don't believe this answer actually answers the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer does say how to open the folder in file explorer, it doesn't answer the question on how to open the folder `WITH` an external program like VSCode. It can be done like so:

```
import { spawn, SpawnOptions } from "child_process";
import { pathExists } from "fs-extra";

const editorPath = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe";

export const launchExternalEditor = async (
  folderPath: string
): Promise<void> => {
  const exists = await pathExists(editorPath);
  if (!exists) {
    console.error("editor not found");
  }

  const opts: SpawnOptions = {
    // Make sure the editor processes are detached from the Desktop app.
    // Otherwise, some editors (like Notepad++) will be killed when the
    // Desktop app is closed.
    detached: true,
  };

  spawn(editorPath, [folderPath], opts);
};
```

This will launch the folder in VSCode as it's root directory. Code is taken from this [repository](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/f09e9ec53e771aa90787ff8e8cb058bf6437f5bc/app/src/lib/editors/launch.ts#L11).

*Note:* this may require some tinkering depending on what program you are trying to use, but so far it worked properly with: VSCode, Visual Studio 2019, Intellij IDEA, NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

For display native system dialogs for opening and saving files, alerting, etc. you can use **dialog** module from electron package.

```
const electron = require('electron');
var filePath = __dirname;
console.log(electron.dialog.showOpenDialog)({
  properties:['openFile'],
  filters:[
    {name:'Log', extentions:['csv', 'log']}
  ]
});
```

A very prompt explanation is provided at [Electron Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog).