# Add a button to open "File Explorer"

Tags: reactjs, electron, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm writing a desktop application using React and Electron. In this application I would like to add a button that, when clicked, will open a "File Explorer" for the user in a specific path.

This means I don't need to select and upload files.

All I need to do is open "File Explorer" so that the user can view the files.
For example: the photo below shows what the user should see

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron open file/directory in specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991267/electron-open-file-directory-in-specific-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secure way to communicate between your [renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process) (i.e. your React code) and your [main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-main-process) is to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file. Then you can use [`shell.openPath()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell#shellopenpathpath) to open the file explorer to a given path. For example:

**Main**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, shell } = require("electron");

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // Link your preload file
    }
  });

  ipcMain.on("openInExplorer", (_event, path) => {
    shell.openPath(path); // Open the given path
  });
});
```

**Preload**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  openInExplorer: (path) => {
    ipcRenderer.send("openInExplorer", path);
  }
});
```

**Renderer**

```js
const handleClick = (path) => {
  window.electronAPI.openInExplorer(path);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! But I get the error "window.electron.openInExplorer is not a function". Perhaps you know what the problem is?

Comment: @Paul Check that your preload is correctly loaded (with a `console.log` for example) and that you have no error in the console. Then check that you configured `contextBridge` correctly.

Comment: I almost understood your logic and understood how to do this in my code. Just a small clarification: I would like the window to open all the time along the following path shell.showItemInFolder('C:\\Users\\<user>\\Music'). Tell me how can I do this?

Comment: @Paul Getting the path of a special folder of the system is a complete different question. You can ask a new one if you want but I answered your current question.

Comment: Yes I understand. I've already dealt with this. But let me ask one thing about our question (I will appreciate your answer): At the moment, "File Explorer" does not open the folder itself, one node higher. That is, If I want to open the "Music" folder along the path 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Music' , then "File Explorer" opens not the "Music" folder, but the <user> folder. And in order to go to the “Music” folder, you need to click the mouse. Is it possible to open the Music folder right away?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure, I never tried... But maybe you can try with `shell.openPath()` instead of `shell.showItemInFolder()`?

Comment: @Paul Using `openPath` worked? I will update my answer if it's the case.

Comment: Yes, openPath() - better solution in it case

Comment: Probably, you can help me with it question too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77906618/17122431