# How to display the default path to a folder

Tags: reactjs, directory, path, electron

The application is written in Electron using React.

I'm working on a feature so that the user can select a folder to download files on their PC. At the moment I have created:

1. a field in which if nothing is selected, the inscription 'Nothing selected' is displayed
2. the "choose folder" button with which the user can select a folder
3. the ability to display the path of the selected folder.

What I would like to add:

At the moment, when you go to a page with this feature, the default field displays the inscription 'Nothing selected', and I would like the path to a specific folder to be displayed by default.

From the documentation I know about **dialog.showOpenDialo**g and **defaultPath**. I tried to implement this, but by default the inscription 'Nothing selected' is still displayed.
Tell me how to make the default path 'C:\Users\nameofuser\Music' displayed

main.ts

```
const os = require('os');

const logUserName = os.userInfo().username;

const defaultFolder = `C:\\Users\\${logUserName}\\Music`

ipcMain.handle(IPCChannels.OpenFolder, async () => {
  let result = '';
  await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    dialog
      .showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openDirectory'],
        defaultPath: defaultFolder,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        result = response.filePaths[0];
        resolve();
      })
  });
  return result;
});
```

OutFolder.tsx

```
 export function OutFolder() {
  const [asset, setAsset] = useState('');
  const getPath = () => {
    window.electron.ipcRenderer
      .invoke(IPCChannels.OpenFolder)
      .then((res) => {
        setAsset(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{asset || 'Nothing selected'}</div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={getPath}>choose folder</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all, you're setting `defaultPath` to the variable `defaultFolderП`, which isn't defined (notice the extra greek pi in the end); second, `defaultPath` only applies to the dialog window which will be opened by the `OpenFolder` handler (this will be the directory which will be displayed when the dialog is opened). Do you just want to display the given path by default? If so, why not expose the default path via IPC, fetch it in the renderer and display it instead of `'Nothing selected'`?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner 1) Thanks for finding the error. I fixed it. 2) Yes, I would like to display the path 'C:\\Users\\nameofuser\\Music' by default, but if the user selects any other path, then display the newly selected path

Comment: So, then what have you tried and what doesn't work? This seems to be pretty straightforward. You could assign the `div` an ID attribute and modify its `textContent` when the page is loaded.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I described in the question and showed what I tried (added defaultPath according to the documentation).
I need to understand the method you suggested, since I have not encountered such a solution

Comment: Then please read the documentation first. As I already said, `defaultPath` *only* applies to the dialog window that will be opened by `getPath()`. Also, if you don't understand what I have suggested, I suggest familiarising yourself with basic web development concepts, specifically manipulating the DOM with JavaScript. There's a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) on MDN.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, if you want a default value just replace the empty string of `useState('')` with what you want.

Comment: @Arkellys Yes, this is the simplest solution to the problem, but not the best. I would like to transfer the default path from main.ts since there I define the path to the folder for each specific user. I changed the code a bit in main.ts. Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentionned in the comments that you would like to get the default path from main to renderer. To do that, you can use an extra IPC handlers and a [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect):

**main.ts**

```js
ipcMain.handle(IPCChannels.GetDefaultPath, () => {
  const logUserName = os.userInfo().username;
  const defaultFolder = `C:\\Users\\${logUserName}\\Music`;

  return defaultFolder;
});
```

**OutFolder.tsx**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.electron.ipcRenderer
    .invoke(IPCChannels.GetDefaultPath)
    .then(setAsset)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}, []);
```

You can also use an extra state `isLoading`/`seIsLoading` if you want to wait for main to return the path before displaying your UI.

---

It's not related t your question, and you have not shared your preload, but seeing you call IPC using `window.electron.ipcRenderer.invoke` makes me worry you expose `ipcRenderer` directly. If it's the case, just be aware that you should not do that for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations).

Comment: Indeed, it is very simple. Why didn't I solve this myself? I probably don't have enough experience. Thank you!

Comment: @Paul We all have to learn at some point. :)