# Open "a href" in Electron jS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I want to open externally a local file, using a firefox plugin I managed to open it from the browser. But in electron JS when I click on the "exe", a pop-up to download the file appears. How do I open my file locally ? Example :

```
<div class="1"><a href="file:///myPathToFile">Press Me</a></div>
<div class="2"><a href="file:///myPathToFile2">Press Me</a></div>
```

I didn't know how to integrate the shell or child command.

Edit : Tried webPreferences: { webSecurity: false } to enable `file://` but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open external file with Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381450/open-external-file-with-electron)

Comment: @Seblor All is see in all those guides are JS scripts. I have no idea how to apply them on my links. What I want is to click and open a file. I tried disabling websecurity but didn't work

Comment: Then I'm afraid you cannot open a file with HTML only.

Comment: @Seblor I did it in firefox thanks to an extension. How come ?

Comment: What's the wider use-case here? Why do you want to use HTML only? Would you be okay with a solution that involves JavaScript?

Comment: @Erick I have multiple links, each one of them uses `a href`.

Comment: I get that, but I don't understand why you need to open a hard-coded file path directly from an anchor link. What kind of files are you trying to open, as well?

Comment: @Erick I'm making a game launcher using ElectronJS to well launch games. So far everything is working when i'm testing with firefox and it plugin.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Browser extensions are JS based, so not HTML only.

Comment: @Seblor. Oright. I just want to be able to launch my executable as I do in firefox using this https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/