# How is it possible to read languages files in Electron

Tags: cordova, electron

I have to include translations files into my electron project.
It is running correctly for Android and iOS with :

```js
cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/res/languages/" + localStorage.getItem("optionlanguage") + ".json";
```

But it does not work with Electron.

What is wrong ?

[EDIT - I can not post an answer]

I used : [Open external file with Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381450/open-external-file-with-electron?rq=2)

I extract file with cordova web service.
I have to change connect-src into CSP.
And it is running.

```js
get_electron('res/languages/fr-FR.json', 'text');

function get_electron(url, responseType) {
    
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url);
        request.responseType = responseType;

        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                //resolve(request.response);
                console.log(request.response);
            } else {
                //reject(Error(request.statusText));
            }
        };

        request.onerror = function() {
            reject(Error("Network Error"));
        };

        request.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: There are several things that could be going wrong.  SUGGESTION: Create a standalone, minimal test project and work through this tutorial: https://phrase.com/blog/posts/building-an-electron-app-with-internationalization-i18n/.  Once you get Electron working with your "test project", it should be straightforward to identify and make the changes you need (code and/or configuration) to your "real" project.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, I am using Cordova-Electron, your example is complicated. How is it possible to add resources to cordova-electron; like this :

`fichiertraduc = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/res/languages/" + localStorage.getItem("optionlanguage") + ".json";  
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fichiertraduc, gotFile, fail);`

Comment: You'll notice the example *DOESN'T* happen to use "localStorage".  I'm more familiar with "native Android" and "cross-platform Flutter" (vs. iOS and/or Electron)  And I assure you there have been *CONSTANT* changes/caveats/restrictions/enhancements regarding "local storage" in both APIs.  Often "security related".  1) I'm *NOT* saying "don't use local storage".  2) I *AM* suggesting that you simply copy/paste the example verbatim, verify "it works" ... and then methodically "work backward" to determine "what's different" between the test example and your app.

Comment: You are using cordova paths, instead of electrons. Cordova will generate the electron project for you but then you need to use electron's folder system.

Comment: paulsm4,  many thanks, I will try that, but it seems that it is more different than cordova project.
@Eric, many thanks, How could I do that ?

Comment: I used : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381450/open-external-file-with-electron?rq=2

I extract file with cordova web service.
I have to change connect-src into CSP.
And it is running.