# How to open Sublime Text with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, electron

I'm working on a file management system built with [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [electron](https://electron.atom.io/).

The file management displays a list of files in a folder and allows the user to run custom commands to batch process the files, such as renaming, custom grouping ect...

However I want to implement a feature that if the user clicks on a file it will open with the text editor of their choice.

I can't get the sublime text editor (or any for that matter) to open with node.js code.

I have looked into other questions here on SO such as "[Launch an external application from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733849/launch-an-external-application-from-node-js)" and "[Is it possible to execute an external program from within node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js)" but none of the answers successfully work for me.

Most of the answers open the file with the "default" program of the operating system which is not what I want. I want to be able to choose the program that opens the file.

I found this code below that calls on global path variables to open external software from node:

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec
exec('yourApp').unref()
```

But of course it doesn't work if you replace 'yourApp' with a file path pointing to sublime_text.exe like so:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe').unref()
```

Any help would be very very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: "C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe" I think there is problem with space. can you remove space and try again? (Or use escape sequence)

Comment: I tried both, using the escape sequence and removing the spaces but neither worked. This was the command run with escape sequences: "C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"

Comment: copy and paste in windows search bar to open sublime_text.exe file using this path "C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe". Is it works fine?

Comment: No that doesn't work, but that's because the OS uses "\" to locate directories where to my understanding node uses "/". If I replace the "/" with "\" then it works.... hmmm let me try escape sequencing that.

Comment: Unfortunately still no go, the javascript string I just tried looks like this:  "C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe" but it didn't run either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out it takes a little bit more code than I first posted to open an external file. The full code looks like this:

```
// Create a child process
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('Path_To_.exe', ['parameters', 'Path_To_File']);
```

Also just in case anyone is wondering it was not necessary to escape sequence the spaces within the file name.

Thank you for everyone who offered to help!

Comment: Also because I didn't clarify it in my answer I wanted to add, if you don't know what "parameters" to add, these are application specific. So if I wanted to run node here I could put "-v" in the parameters to have node print out it's version in the console. However there are no parameters that I need for sublime text so I left this blank and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this as your path:
C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe

Comment: the spaces need to be escaped, and it should work for you

Comment: That was similar to what Harsh Patel suggested in the comments, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried your exact path as well, but no go. If it helps I'm running the "exec("C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe").unref();" line inside of the "appReady" function of electron. I tried the same thing with pure node.js, but same result no response.