# How to open a .csv (or any extension) file in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, file, csv

I have a csv file and I want to open it (in excel) with plain javascript.

I've searched a lot of websites and none of them seem to have the answer.

**ANSWER**

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('start ./csv/Fixture.csv', (err, stdout, stderr) => {});
```

Comment: `open it (in excel) with plain javascript` can you clarify this nonsensical statement - did you want to use node.js to open a selected csv file in excel? you'll want to use something in [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) - the answer coming from stackoverflow, so not sure how you missed it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/how-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js

Comment: You want your code in a browser to run a local application on a user's machine?

Comment: I mentioned "plain javascript" because every website was posting about using javascript on a browser

Comment: @G.Cunha I just noticed your edit with a solution. It's perfectly acceptable in Stack Overflow to write both a question and an answer with it. However, you should post the answer as an actual answer, so (among other reasons) it can be voted up and down as other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use node.js or some sort of server to deliver the payload or the csv file to a JavaScript buffer such as via a websocket. Client side browser JS is a sandbox and you need to get your data from the server, or use node.js server to write javascript that runs on the server and can access files, but I think you mean you want to access a csv file on a webpage, and to do that you would need to have server side code send it to you, by using a XHR or WebSocket transfer.

Comment: This is an app that runs locally

Comment: What is your JS engine? Not stating that is probably why you got downvoted, if it is node.js, use child_process as suggested in comment on main question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733849/launch-an-external-application-from-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Use the new HTML anchor tag attribute, for example:

```
<a href="abc.csv" download> Click Here... </a>
```